# Getting ClassCastException

Tags: java, json

I have an Iterator to generate objects from a JSON-format. But unfortunately I get a

> ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject at Main.Test.main(Test.java:33)

My *Test* class are as below:

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); 

      try {
         Object jsonData = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\b\\Desktop\\test.json"));
         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonData;

         JSONIteratorAuthor itr = new JSONIteratorAuthor(jsonObject);
         while(itr.hasNext()){
            al.add(itr.next());
         }

         while(itr.hasNext()){
             Object element = itr.next();
             System.out.print(element + "");
         }        
     } 
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

The exception relates to this line: `JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonData;`

I really don't understand why it doesn't work. I hope someone can help me.
I use the json.simple library.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you saved your data as type org.json.simple.JSONArray.
Try casting

```
JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) jsonData;
```

instead of

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonData;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `JSON object` and `JSON array` are valid roots of JSON data. There's no way to query the json-simple parser what type of data comes from the call

```
Object jsonData = parser.parse(data);
```

I guess you have to use `instanceof` to check what type you get and then cast accordingly. Note that `JSONArray` does not extend `JSONObject`, so you can't cast between the two.